# Tab Bar and Nav Bar don't appear using present function

Tags: swift3

I have an app with 5 tabs. The Home tab displays blog posts and has a nav bar and tab bar. The last tab in the app is the user profile controller. I have a logout button. When the user logs out, I segue to the home tab, yet the nav bar and tab bar are not appearing.  The code for the `logOff` button on the Profile tab:

```
if isUserLoggedIn {
    loginButton.setTitle("LogIn", for: UIControlState.normal)
    appUserID = ""
    isUserLoggedIn = false
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PostViewController") as! PostViewController
    self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
} else {
...
```

Comment: The code in question doesn't actually use a segue. You use `self.present` for navigation, which is not the same as a segue.

Comment: Good point.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should present the **tab bar controller** if you want it to be shown, not it's associated view controller. Assign a Storyboard ID to the tab bar controller and present it.

Comment: Ha!  Never would have thought of that.  Thanks!  Can't mark as solved for five minutes.  Thanks again.